# JQuery click function works once, but required to work many

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that removes a div within another, and replaces it with a video when a link is clicked (which is in the div that was removed).

When the video finishes, the video is removed, the div that was removed is placed BACK into the div.

The problem is, if I am to click the link again, no response.

Any ideas?

JQuery Code

```
$('#panl-one a#watch-now').click(function(){
        var copy = $('#panl-one').html();
        $('#panl-one').html('<video width="334" height="200" controls muted autoplay title="Video" id="myvideo"><source src="My Movie.mp4"></video>');
        var video= $('#myvideo')[0]; 
        var videoJ= $('#myvideo');        
        videoJ.on('ended',function(){
            $('#myvideo').hide();
            $('#panl-one').html('<div><p><a href="#" id="watch-now">Watch again?</a></p></div>');   
        });
        return false;
});
```

HTML code

```
<div class="video" id="panl-one" title="this is the panel title">
    <div>
    <a href="#" class="get-link-name" id="link-one">This is the video title</a>
    <p>Video
    <a href="#" id="watch-now">watch now</a>
    04:09
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just removed the element you're clicking, and replaced it with another element, that's why it only works once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation.

Change the following line:

```
$('#panl-one a#watch-now')
```

to

```
$('body').on('click', '#panl-one a#watch-now', function(){
```

This delegates the click from that element to the body, regardless of if it has been removed or replaced in the DOM.

*note* For better performance, bind it to the closest static parent element, instead of the body.